# How to execute a :cabbr in a function?

Tags: vim

I have a :cabbr that goes :

```
:cabbr fil v/<c-r><c-w>/d
```

and I wish to execute it in a function (the cursor is already correctly positioned).

How should I proceed ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think a command line abbreviation will work in a function. You could do `exec 'v/<c-r><c-w>/d'` in a function or use `expand('<cword>')` which is the same a `<c-r><c-w>`

Comment: why not just in your function execute the `:g/:v` command directly? it is independent on the `ab` settings, and making your script more generic

Comment: @FDinoff : I had tried that, but it did not work. To be more precise, I have, e.g. 6 lines containing Foo and 4 containing Bar ; the cursor, at that stage in the function is positioned on Bar ; thus v/Bar/d should leave me with 4 lines. But, in fact, it deletes all lines, and I do not understand why. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Kent : I do not understand - and I prefer to admit it - what you suggest. How should I implement this ? I had another idea, which was to have the function "prompt" for an answer : "What word are you looking for ?" which would allow me to search, e.g. for v/.*Foo\|Bar/d or v/.*Foo\&Bar/d etc... but I simply do not know how to do that. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cabbrev abc echo 'foo'

function! Foo()
    call feedkeys(':abc ^M')
endfunction
```

*(`^M` in this case is pressing `<c-v><cr>`.)*

Now `:call Foo()` will output `foo`.

EDIT: As people pointed out in the comments, `feedkeys(':abc ^M')` can also be replaced by `feedkeys(":abc\<cr>")`.

Comment: @ThG Any feedback on this answer?

Comment: sorry, I was out for a short time. I tried your answer and transformed it just a bit : 1) I kept my :cabbr as it was and 2) inserted in my function : call feed keys(":fil\<c-r>") and it worked. Thank you for bringing me to the solution. This is why I accept your answer. Thanks you very much

Comment: This could lead to very unexpected behavior when using the function as feed keys queues the key strokes and they get run after the function ends. (and maybe other functions if Foo was executed with in a function) For example if you but an `echo 'bar'` after `feedkeys` bar would be printed before foo.

Comment: Instead of using `^M` you could just use `\<CR>` if the string passed to feedkeys is in double quotes. `feedkeys(":abc \<CR>")` is equivalent to `feedkeys(':abc ^M')`

Comment: Well, the solution is hacky, no doubts about that. And yup, ThG's answer reminded me of the `\<cr>` solution. (I noticed his typo.) But I tend to forget about it, since I try to use single quotes as often as possible. Just my personal style, I guess. I upvote both of you! :-)